# ScrollView Memory Leaks with Button Style

Tags: macos, swiftui

**Hi There, I have found a suspicious memory leak when I use Scroll View, List or anything else to list a View**
[image]
This is how Scroll View with Lazy Grid is defined:

```
struct TravelingView1: View {
    
    var body: some View {
            ScrollView {
                LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.flexible())]) {
                    ForEach(0..<10) {_ in
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(height: 20)
                    }
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 200)
    }
}
```

And Button Style in the View as:

```
struct ScreenView1: View {
    @ObservedObject var drawRadioButtonViewModel: DrawRadioButtonViewModel1
    var body: some View {
        RadioButton(type: .radioButton, toggle: drawRadioButtonViewModel.isRadioCheck,
                    identifier: "Quick Split",
                    radioWidth: 302,
                    action: { [weak drawRadioButtonViewModel] in
            drawRadioButtonViewModel?.updateToggleCheck()
        },
                    label: {})
        .offset(x: -CGFloat(100)/2, y: CGFloat(100))
        
        Button(drawRadioButtonViewModel.isRadioCheck ? "Checked" : "Unchecked", action: { [weak drawRadioButtonViewModel] in
            drawRadioButtonViewModel?.updateToggleCheck()
        })
            .offset(x: -CGFloat(100)/2, y: CGFloat(100) + 30)
    }
}
```

With Button Style as:

```
struct RadioButton<Content: View>: View {
    let type: Button_styles
    let toggle: Bool
    var isDisable: Bool = false
    let identifier: String
    var radioWidth: Int
    let action: () -> Void
    let label: () -> Content

    enum Button_styles {
        case radioButton
        case checkBox
    }

    init(type: Button_styles, toggle: Bool, isDisable: Bool = false, identifier: String, radioWidth: Int, action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.type = type
        self.action = action
        self.radioWidth = radioWidth
        self.label = label
        self.toggle = toggle
        self.isDisable = isDisable
        self.identifier = identifier
    }

    init(action: @escaping () -> Void, @ViewBuilder label: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.init(type: .radioButton, toggle: Bool(), isDisable: Bool(), identifier: String(), radioWidth: Int(), action: action, label: label)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: action, label: label)
            .buttonStyle(RadioButtonStyle(toggle: toggle,
                                          isDisable: isDisable,
                                          identifier: identifier,
                                          radioWidth: radioWidth,
                                          action: action))
        
    }
}

struct RadioButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    var toggle: Bool
    var isDisable: Bool
    var identifier: String
    var radioWidth: Int
    var action: () -> Void
    func makeBody(configuration _: Configuration) -> some View {
        ZStack {
            if isDisable {
                DisableRadioButton(identifier: identifier, radioWidth: radioWidth, action: action)
            } else {
                if toggle {
                    SelectedRadioButton(identifier: identifier, radioWidth: radioWidth, action: action)
                } else {
                    NormalRadioButton(identifier: identifier, radioWidth: radioWidth, action: action)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct SelectedRadioButton: View {
    var identifier: String
    var radioWidth: Int
    var action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        let offsetX = radioWidth / 2 + 20/2 + 12
        ZStack {
            Image("common_check_on")
                .frame(width: CGFloat(20), height: CGFloat(20))
            Text(identifier)
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.75), radius: 1, x: 1, y: 1)
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .frame(width: CGFloat(radioWidth), height: CGFloat(20), alignment: .leading)
                .offset(x: CGFloat(offsetX), y: 0)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .onTapGesture {
                    action()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct NormalRadioButton: View {
    var identifier: String
    var radioWidth: Int
    var action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        let offsetX = radioWidth / 2 + 20/2 + 12
        ZStack {
            Image("common_check_off")
                .frame(width: CGFloat(20), height: CGFloat(20))
            Text(identifier)
                .shadow(color: .black.opacity(0.75), radius: 1, x: 1, y: 1)
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .frame(width: CGFloat(radioWidth), height: CGFloat(20), alignment: .leading)
                .offset(x: CGFloat(offsetX), y: 0)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
                .onTapGesture {
                    action()
                }
        }
    }
}

struct DisableRadioButton: View {
    var identifier: String
    var radioWidth: Int
    var action: () -> Void
    var body: some View {
        let offsetX = radioWidth / 2 + 20/2 + 12
        ZStack {
            Image("common_check_off")
                .frame(width: CGFloat(20), height: CGFloat(20))
            Text(identifier)
                .font(.system(size: 15))
                .frame(width: CGFloat(radioWidth), height: CGFloat(20), alignment: .leading)
                .offset(x: CGFloat(offsetX), y: 0)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
                .onTapGesture {
                    action()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't have any clue to find out where cause this leak.

Demo Leaks Git: https://github.com/KuroPiii/SuspiciousMemoryLeaksLazyGrid